# On a planet with Arrakis-style sandstorms, could a single windbreak protect much of a city?

Tags: environment, weather, cities

Planet has wind that flies at an indistinct speed - fast enough to fling razor sharp debris around though that's what I have built. I will tweak it as necessary but they are considered life threatening, at least when there's such debris.

The people of these planets have taken to building great windbreaks to protect their buildings though one in particular, in a very unfortunate circumstance, has had to take to building a makeshift one. The buildings are tightly packed due to the circumstances and I wonder if the bubble of safety will continue on until the limits of the city or if some will be exposed the further out you get. I don't have definite measurements, but if the initial windbreak can lift the winds floor up above the roofs, do you suppose the roofs could keep it up without causing too much damage? I assume debris will still cause issues but only indirectly.

Answer (score 6):

**No, but maybe yes**

[image]
*Click on image to expand. Image courtesy [Research Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Air-flow-around-a-windbreak-showing-the-extent-of-various-microclimate-zones-in-terms-of_fig3_233865614).*

Sand (or any other small particulate debris) is insidious. It will get into the smallest creacks. A windbreak will lift the storm above the rooftops and keep it there briefly, but eventually, the force of the wind comes to bear on the rooftops.

Therefore, the windrbreaks are doing what you want and producing the circumstance you want. But what next?

If your rooftops are *tightly interlocked* such that the force of the storm cannot work its way between seams. So long as you have rationalized a design that "locks out" the storm such that only parallel force is applied to the community's roof tops and not perpendicular force to its walls, then you have what you need.

**Would multiple windbreaks help?**

No. Ignoring some details, only the last windbreak in line matters. A series of gradually higher windbreaks will withstand more force than one fearsome windbreak, but in terms of what they're protecting... only the last windbreak matters.

**What if my windbreak is really, really, really tall?**

it would have to be incredibly tall. If you click the link at the top of my answer you'll find some basic equations for the protected zone. We can take advantage of both the protected and turbulent zones such that your city can be a maximum of 28X the height of the trees. So, a 30 meter tree will protect a city that's 0.84 km wide. That's a good sized city! If Paris were a perfect circle it's diamter would be 7km. Unfortunately, that means you need a windbreak 250 meters tall.

Note that the image I linked to suggests that your buildings don't want to be more than 1/2 the height of the windbreak.

**But does it matter if the wind is full force later?**

This is where my original suggestion kicks in. If we assume you have a roof top design that's designed for the force of the storm *skittering across the top of the roofs,* then the city can be as wide as you want. All you need is to lift the storm so that the perpendicular force isn't tearing at the city.